# Sending data by HTTP GET to a PHP server

Tags: java, php, android

I am building an app in which user can select his/her gender , favorite food , their anger , favorite color , their age and etc ...

I passed these DATA to my final activity with Intent .
Now I am trying to send the answers to a PHP server (which works fine) and get an answer (which city suits you most)

here is my code , I don't know what is wrong with it (I've added the permission to connect to the internet)
When i run the app it works fine untill the last activity is clicked , then it force closes the app

```
public class result extends AppCompatActivity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.result);


    TextView result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

    final String gender;
    Intent a = getIntent();
    gender = a.getStringExtra("gender");
    final String anger;
    Intent b = getIntent();
    anger = b.getStringExtra("hate");
    final String food;
    Intent c = getIntent();
    food = c.getStringExtra("food");
    final String gettowork;
    Intent d = getIntent();
    gettowork = d.getStringExtra("gotowork");
    final String settelment;
    Intent ee = getIntent();
    settelment = ee.getStringExtra("house");
    final String actor;
    Intent f = getIntent();
    actor = f.getStringExtra("star");
    final String weather;
    Intent g = getIntent();
    weather = g.getStringExtra("weather");
    final String weekend;
    Intent h = getIntent();
    weekend = h.getStringExtra("weekend");
    final String color;
    Intent j = getIntent();
    color = j.getStringExtra("color");
    final String age;
    Intent i10 = getIntent();
    age = i10.getStringExtra("age");


HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://test123.com/games/whichcity/app/check-form.php?gender=" + gender + "&anger=" + anger + "&food=" + food + "&gettowork=" + gettowork + "&settlement=" + settelment + "&actor=" + actor + "&weather=" + weather + "&weekend=" + weekend + "&color=" + color + "&age=" + age);
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    try {
        InputStream webs = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webs,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        result.setText(reader.readLine());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();



}}}
```

Android Manifest File

```
<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".splash_screen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".firstquestion"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".secondquestion"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".thirdquestion"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".fourthquestion"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".fifthquestion"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".sixthquestion"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".seventhquestion"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".eighthquestion"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".ninethquestion"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".result"></activity>


</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and my error in the logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.vaya_group.charactertest/org.vaya_group.charactertest.result}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2071)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                           Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                              at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1126)
                                                                              at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
                                                                              at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
                                                                              at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
                                                                              at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
                                                                              at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
                                                                              at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
                                                                              at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
                                                                              at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
                                                                              at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
                                                                              at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
                                                                              at org.vaya_group.charactertest.result.onCreate(result.java:86)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556) 
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting ?

Comment: We see what goes wrong. And you can see it too. And you did not tell what really happens to your app. Well you will know what goes wrong if you look in the LogCat. Post the relevant lines.

Comment: What is the problem after executing this code? Post the relevant lines of logcat.

Comment: Post manifest file.

Comment: You should post more of the logcat. The real reason is in it. Look further. Look for all exceptions.

Comment: `Now I am trying to send the answers to a PHP server (which works fine)` ??? Really? This does really look like sending fails.

Comment: @greenapps I mean it's alright on the php side

Comment: @Defozo i updated the question

Comment: @greenapps check the catlog now

Comment: mr_tkp i updated the question

Comment: Well why are you not mentioning the other exception `Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` ? This exception was to be expected seeing your network code in `onCreate()`.

Comment: @vaya-group execption you are getting is because, quote from [developer.android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) _The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this exception because you are attempting to perform a networking operation in UI thread. Instead of this you can have your network operation in another thread or implement some better ways which ultimately put the operation in another thread. These better ways are using **AsyncTask** or using **Volley**. I will definitely put my votes for Volley as it is simple and neat.

GET operation implementing volley,

```
// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://test123.com/games/whichcity/app/check-form.php?gender=" + gender + "&anger=" + anger + "&food=" + food + "&gettowork=" + gettowork + "&settlement=" + settelment + "&actor=" + actor + "&weather=" + weather + "&weekend=" + weekend + "&color=" + color + "&age=" + age;

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        //handle response from server
        result.setText(response);
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        //handle error
        result.setText("That didn't work!");
    }
});
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Inorder to Volley to work, you should add dependency in your gradle.
In your Gradle file (Module:app), add `compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'` in dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

[Learn more about Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Happy coding!